# Xcode: Cannot start the application on Device (ExperitestServer: level was set to: (3))

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, build

As I build and run the application on Xcode for installing the app on an iPhone 3GS, Xcode suddenly stops the process (before even starting the application) and logs this:

```
ExperitestServer: level was set to: (3)
```

what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Testing team was using ExperiTest for testing automation. It has nothing to do with Xcode. I contacted the ExperiTest.com for that matter.